# What exact connector is this?

Tags: connector, identification, cable-assemblies

I'm trying figure out what connector this is? The pitch is 2mm. I believe it may be a type of JST connector.

connector:
[image]

mate:
[image]

pitch:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A quick look on the [JST website](http://www.jst.com/home21.html) turned up [this](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=189) product family which looks like the connector you have. Specifically part number PAP-04V-S. If you download the CAD model you should be able to verify it.